# Oracle to Mysql timestamp data is not importing

Tags: mysql, oracle, datetime, csv, timestamp

I am trying to load data from CSV (which is generated by oracle table) to MySQL table.

**Sample CSV file content:**

**ID,   Number,   CreationTimeStamp,          ModifiedTimestamp**

64282,44000000,26-JUN-13 03.18.48.235000 PM,26-JUN-13 03.18.55.929157 PM

64283,44000000,26-JUN-13 03.25.45.013000 PM,26-JUN-13 03.25.52.015622 PM

64286,40000000,27-JUN-13 03.14.33.198000 PM,27-JUN-13 03.14.39.090887 PM

When i load data into MySQL (Using LOAD DATA INFILE...)i get zeros in CreationTimeStamp and ModifiedTimestamp fields.

**MySQL after loading from CSV:**

| 64282 | 44000000 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

| 64283 | 44000000 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

| 64286 | 40000000 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

What is the data type i should use to import timestamp values? What is the equivalent datatype for Oracle's TIMESTAMP datatype in MySQL?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21948/how-to-import-timestamp-from-a-csv-file) helps you.

Comment: you can use [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` to transform the oracle date string into a mysql date

Comment: Used **str_to_date** function while loading but its taking current date and time. [ 2014-08-06 11:46:46]

Answer (score 1):

First you import data as VARCHAR then you need to convert it like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26-JUN-13 03.18.55.929157','%d-%M-%y %H.%i.%s');
```

Comment: Wanted to import as it is in CSV and i have huge files to import.

Comment: try this `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Path/To/CSV/file.csv'  
INTO TABLE tbl1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1,col2,@date1,@date2)
SET @date1 = STR_TO_DATE(@date1,'%d-%M-%y %h.%i.%s'),@date2 = STR_TO_DATE(@date2,'%d-%M-%y %h.%i.%s'); `

Comment: Its working..thanks. But i want to retain the same format as "26-JUN-13 03.18.55"

Comment: you can't store in mysql datetime the format you want but you can get that format by doing this `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_column,'%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s')` pls rate my above answer if it was useful, thank you